# How to concat binding value with different variables in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to concat different variables but I am getting parse error;

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
```

Is there any way to concat a binding variable like below?

```
<ng-template let-item="item">
    <input type=text [src]="myObject.urls.{{item.id}}">
</ng-template>
```

**EDIT:** What I want to get is like;

```
<input type=text [src]="myObject.urls.33322222">
```

I got an object;

```
myObject = {urls: {33322222: "someUrlValue"}};
```

Comment: `[src]="'myObject.urls.' + item.id"` or `src="myObject.urls.{{item.id}}"`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use square brackets to access computed object properties:

```
<input type=text [src]="myObject.urls[item.id]">
```